# Tizen Docs give C headers but not Lib names?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, tizen, tizen-native-app

Trying to implement some Unity3D C# plugin code but am finding the Tizen docs to be rather lacking.

I need to know what Lib names are used for specific headers.  Such as the message box api: https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__MESSAGING__MESSAGES__MODULE.html#ga32013c0d16b46a60be3f837c6474e4be

It tells me the header required but not the lib its used in.  BlackBerry, MS and Apple all list this in there docs and is part of normal doc gen.  Why Tizen doesn't give you this is beyond me.  Is there an easy quick way to find this info?  Thought someone might know.

Here is the location to lib: C:\tizen-sdk\platforms\mobile-2.3\rootstraps\mobile-2.3-device.core
Would be nice to know what lib goes with what header.

Looks like it might be: libcapi-messaging-messages.so

Answer (score 1):

Yes, someone seems to think it's a good idea for those libraries to be opaque to the reader, not sure why.  The set of "open source" libraries, including the EFL ones, are normally identified by name, but the Tizen-specific part is not.  Will try to find out the motivation. It has caused me some problems as well (yes I know in the stackoverflow parlance this is not an "answer")